# Python Web interface for simple mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, web

We need a new web interface for our internal car booking system, which is implemented in mysql database. Could somebody please advise, what would be a suitable solution (which framework, if any). The main criteria is **simplicity** and future **maintainability**. We therefore would like some clean, minimalistic solution.

Once completed, the interface will be expected to be running for many years (5-10). We would therefore like to use some technology, which is likely to be around in 5-10 years time.

We would like to implement it in python.

Comment: You might want to check out `flask`, which is a python microframework. SQLite integration is easy, not sure about mysql though.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) -- a simple, easy and very (most?) popular web framework in Python.

A little overview:

Django follows the Model-View-Templates paradigm. Models abstract the database tables as classes. The fields in a class can refer to various data types and relationships.

The Views encapsulate your business logic. In fact, Django provides some generic views, which can reduce the need for writing certain amount of code.

Finally, the templates are used to render the HTML pages.

Last but not the least, Django automatically generates an admin interface that helps you easily maintain your data. All these pages can be easily customized.

Please refer to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/) for further details. A lot of tutorials are available in the Web.